# Hibernate ElementCollection/CollectionTable using existing field as JoinColumn#referencedColumnName in audited Entity

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

We have the following data structure:

```
@Audited(WithModifiedFlag = true)
@Entity
public class A {
  private int id;

  @Id
  @DocumentId
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
  public int getId() {
    return id;  
  }

  private UUID uuid;

  @Column( name = "uuid", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)" )
  public UUID getUuid() {
    return uuid;
  }

  private String name;

  @Column( name = "name" )
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  
  private Set<String> relatedA = new HashSet<>();

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable( name = "a_to_a",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "a_right", referencedColumnName = "uuid" ) )
  @Column( name = "a_left" )
  @NotAudited
  public Set<String> getRelatedA() {
    return relatedA;
  }
}
```

The problem is, that this gives us a `MappingException` claiming `Duplicate property mapping` for the modified_flag column of `uuid`.

I am assuming that `JoinColumn` in this context expects a non-existent field in `referencedColumnName` and automatically attempts creating the audit fields required?

The whole thing works if we add `@NotAudited` to `getUuid()` and I don't quite understand why.